# Generate CPU, memory, disk and network graphs from command-line

Tags: command-line-interface, image, graph

I would like to periodically (e.g. using cron) generate an image (e.g. png) containing graphs for CPU usage, memory usage, disk I/O load and network usage.

I would like something not too ugly, so a `gnuplot` graph is a bit crude, but if that's the only option I'll take it nonetheless.

After half an hour of googling, I just havn't been able to find a simple tool to do that without extensive configuration.

I thought about using `conky` and asking it to render to a file instead of showing the graphs on the screen, but I couldn't find such an option for `conky`. The only solution I thought of would be to start a dummy Xorg session, let conky run on that, and periodically take screenshots.

I also saw plenty of blog posts etc. about using `dstat` or similar tools, but these generated text reports, not graphs.

**Is there a command-line tool that is very simple to setup that can generate (pretty) GPU graphs and similar graphs, without requiring extensive configuration from my part?**

Something like:

```
generategraph --cpu --interval 300 --output mygraph.png
```

**Edit:**

The problem with the other tools cited so far (rrdtool, mrtg, zabbix, orca) is that they are enterprise-grade software designed for full-time network administrators. I just want something simple that I can run on a small box and set-up within a matter of seconds instead of spending days to configure it.

And I just realized I asked on serverfault instead of superuser like I meant to, so that explains the answers I got :) Thank you all, and sorry for loosing your time, I'm requesting this question to be closed / migrated to superuser.

Comment: That doesn't mean that they're unsuitable for what you're asking for. MRTG is quite easy to set up.

Comment: I found this question while looking to do the same thing on my home server. I did install vnstat and vnstati to generate png of network usage, but was missing ram and cpu and only a few hours later did i find anything about sysstat and sar2png

sysstat - System performance tools for the Linux operating system
Contains: sar collects, reports and saves system activity information
sadf displays data collected by sar in multiple formats (CSV, XML, JSON, etc.) and can be used for data exchange with other programs.

And sar2png https://github.com/sqrt529/sar2png

Answer (score 6):

Think about this... You need some way to track history in order to provide an input to the CLI-generated graphs. This is where something like [RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) helps.

There are tools like [collectl](http://collectl.sourceforge.net) that will collect data and organize it for another [graphing utility](http://collectl-utils.sourceforge.net).

There are pretty solutions like [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com) that aren't CLI-based, but provide some [better insight into system performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nB7t.png)...

But I'm old school... I still use [Orca](https://www.orcaware.com/orca/) for this.

But the graphs are pretty.

[image]

Comment: Indy_Fruit?  Pray tell...

Answer (score 2):

Any of:

- rrdtool
- MRTG
- Zabbix

will take care of your problem.

Comment: Other solutions: cacti ?

Comment: And a lot of others besides.

Answer (score 2):

Heavens. What's wrong with [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/)? Or, almost any other performance monitoring tool ever?